# HTML5 Video not working in iPhone and iPad

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am working on a web app where i need to add video tag which is to be compatible for all devices. I use the below JavaScript code to add video

```
var src = "some mp4 file source";
var video = document.createElement("video");
video.width = 600;
video.height = 400;
video.controls = true;
video.autoplay = true;
video.preload = "auto";
video.src = src;
element.appendChild(video);
```

The above code works fine in all browsers which have compatible with HTML5 and in all devices except iPhone and iPad which shows some error occurred.

What am i missing ?

Comment: I suggest `remote debugging`, try Google that ;)

Comment: Have you tried any other video files? It may be a codec issue. From apple's specs: 
Video formats supported: H.264 video up to 1080p, 60 frames per second, High Profile level 4.2 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; MPEG-4 video up to 2.5 Mbps, 640 by 480 pixels, 30 frames per second, Simple Profile with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps per channel, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats; Motion JPEG (M-JPEG) up to 35 Mbps, 1280 by 720 pixels, 30 frames per second, audio in ulaw, PCM stereo audio in .avi file format

Comment: Specs: (TV & Video section) https://support.apple.com/kb/SP708?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: @BrianD Will try it out...!

Comment: @BrianD Even the video captured in iphone doesn't play in the web app..!

Answer (score 0):

This code will be better if you want to implement a video that will work on any devices

```
<video width="600" height="400" autoplay>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here de documentation that you will need: 
[html5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)